# ¿Por qué Google.chart no carga desde windows.open?

Tags: javascript

con el siguiente código creo correctamente la nueva página tal y como quiero que se muestre (incluyendo las variables y arreglos), el problema es que google.chart no se despliega, en cambio, si cojo y pongo el HTML de la pagina creada en otro documento a parte, este si se muestra. Lo estoy visualizando todo desde Open With Live Server, y no sé si va está ahí el problema, sé que la linea del script de google chart tiene que desplegar una vez cargada otras 3 líneas CDN, esto no pasa, por lo tanto no se carga. Os comparto el código:

```
var nuevaVentana = window.open('/cicloextendido.html', '_Blank');

var inicioHTML = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <html lang="es">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ciclo Extendido Nº: ${indice + 1}</title>
  <style> .negativo {color: red;} .positivo {color: green;} body {margin: 5% !important;} </style>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body> 
  <div id="chart-container"></div>
 `

var finHTML = `
<script type="text/javascript">
// Crear el gráfico
function drawChart() {
  var data = [
    ['Operación', 'Capital'],
    ${arrCapitalGraficoExtensoCopiado2.join('\n')}
  ];
  var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

  var options = {
    title: 'Ventas anuales',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart-container'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

`

```
nuevaVentana.document.write(inicioHTML);  //modificar esto
nuevaVentana.document.write(arrResultadoOperaciones[indice] + finHTML);
```

`

EDIT: el problema no esta ahí, el problema esta en que no se ejecuta ningún script desde esa página.

Gracias por vuestro tiempo!!

Answer (score 0):

Después de muchos intentos logre lo que buscabas, basado en parte en este post de [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310680/how-can-i-run-a-script-in-another-newly-opened-tab). El script me carga, solo que tu código no me funciona porque me faltan funciones y variables que estan definidas en otro lado, pero lo que hagas con el script ya es cosa tuya:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css" />
  <title>untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="btn-danger"></div>    
  <script src="scripts2.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
let nuevaVentana = window.open('./cicloextendido.html', '_Blank'); // referencia a la nueva ventana

nuevaVentana.addEventListener("load",() => { // al cargar la nueva ventana:
  /* agregando los modulos del head a la nueva ventana*/
  nuevaVentana.document.head.innerHTML = 
  `<html lang="es">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ciclo Extendido Nº: ${1}</title>
  <style> .negativo {color: red;} .positivo {color: green;} body {margin: 5% !important;} </style>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`
  /* agregando etiquetas del body a la nueva ventana*/
  nuevaVentana.document.body.innerHTML = 
  `<div id="chart-container"></div>
   <div class="btn-danger">modulo bootstrap cargado desde el head de la nueva ventana</div>`
  /* el div btn-danger es para que veas que el cdn de bootstrap dentro del head se esta cargando */
  loadMyScript(nuevaVentana); /* funcion que agregara el script, le pasamos la referencia a la nueva ventana  */
})

function loadMyScript(mywindow){
  mywindow.myScript = function(){ /* agregamos una propiedad a la ventana nueva, que contendra una funcion */
    let script = document.createElement("SCRIPT") /* creamos una etiqueta */
    /* le agregamos el codigo a la etiqueta */
    script.innerHTML = `
    console.log("script ejecutandose en la nueva pestaña!!!")
    function drawChart() {
      let data = [
        ['Operación', 'Capital'],
        "variable desconocida"
      ];
      let dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
      let options = {
        title: 'Ventas anuales',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'bottom' }
      };
      let chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart-container'));
      chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    }
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    `
    mywindow.document.body.appendChild(script) /* hacemos append del script sobre el body de la nueva ventana */
  }
  mywindow.myScript() /* llamamos a la funcion, se cargara el script */
}
```

Y así como cargas este script podes cargar otros, agregar etiquetas en el body de la nueva pestaña, etc.

No sé de Chartjs y por eso no puedo hacer funcionar tu script pero la idea de cargarlo en una pestaña nueva se aplica, después está en vos usar el script como desees. Boostrap (que si se usar) me está cargando correctamente y por eso agregue un botón rojo para que lo veas.

Perdón por el formato, estoy poniendo código entre cadenas literales (debería mostrarse como string) y este editor se vuelve loco y lo coloca como código, pero funciona.